# Question about "the nature of the gas" (TD transfomations)

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, reversibility

$n = 1$ mol of a perfect gas pass from an initial state $A$ to a state $B$ though an isothermal transformation where $T_A = 300 $K and $V_B = 2V_A$.

Then from $B$ to $C$ though an isochoric transformation where $T_C = 189$ K, and finally an adiabatic transformation from $C$ to $F$, where $V_F = V_A$.

Assume all the transformations are reversible.

Ok, besides the usual question, there is this one which I really don't get:

- What must be the nature of the gas so that the final state $F$ does coincide with the state $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have already written down all the known values of the process, preferably organised so that you can easily see what is happening.

The question is really just asking you what particular type of ideal gas this has to be, in order for this overall process to actually be a cyclical process. In particular, the specific value of 189K (not exact) is needed so that the last remaining free parameter describing the family of ideal gases can be fixed to the famous value that you definitely have learnt, pinning it down to the specific type.

Comment: Thank you! I indeed managed to express the related parameters in a way that I could be able to find $\gamma = 1.666$, though this is not a "famous value", if that is what you meant...

Comment: That is the famous value. What does $\gamma=\frac53$ mean for an ideal gas?

Comment: Ohh, I didn't see it! Using the calculator I directly got $1.666$ without passing through the fraction. Thank you!!

Comment: Because of the finite number of digits in 189K, and I get more quickly and naturally $\gamma-1=0.666576$, the calculator can never give you the correct exact fraction. You kind of need to have the idea beforehand what values they should be, and mentally compensate for slight deviation from theoretically exact values.